# Semantic-UI Sidebar.Pusher causing react router to rerender its component

Tags: reactjs, react-router, semantic-ui, react-router-dom, semantic-ui-react

I am using the react router and semantic-ui sidebar. When the sidebar is toggled between visible and invisible, the router triggers its component (`OilBarrelComponent`) to be recreated (rather than just 'pushed'). This seems unnecessary and has side effects that i don't want. Is there something wrong with my code that causes the `OilBarrelContainer` component to be recreated just because I toggle the sidebar?

```
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Link, Switch} from 'react-router-dom';
import {Sidebar, Segment, Button, Menu, Icon} from 'semantic-ui-react'

  toggleSidebarVisibility = () => this.setState({ sidebarVisible: !this.state.sidebarVisible })

  render() {
    const { sidebarVisible } = this.state

    return (
    <Router history={history}>
      <div>
        <Sidebar.Pushable className="phsidebar" as={Segment}>
          <Sidebar as={Menu} animation='push' width='thin'  visible={sidebarVisible} icon='labeled' vertical inverted>
            <Menu.Item className="sidebaritem" as={Link} to='/oilbarrel'>
              Gauge
            </Menu.Item>
          </Sidebar>
          <Sidebar.Pusher>
            <div>
              <MessagesContainer/>
              <Switch>
                <Route exact path="/" component={() => (<Home />)}/>
                <Route exact path="/oilbarrel" component={() => (<OilBarrelContainer timer={true} topMargin={0} width={300} height={400} labelText={"Diesel"}/>)}/>
              </Switch>
            </div>
          </Sidebar.Pusher>
        </Sidebar.Pushable>
      </div>

    </Router>
    )};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect it's that your `<Route>`'s `component` props are functions rather than just a reference to the component classes.

I.e. instead of

```
component={() => (<Home />)}
```

I believe it should be

```
component={Home}
```

I believe the former way re-renders a completely new component on every render, so there is no way for React to assert that a re-render is unnecessary.